# How VSCODE or VIM generate all the fields in a class/struct

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim

For example, I had a c++ struct like:

```
struct MyStruct{
    bool isValid0;
    bool isValid1;
    bool isValid2;
    bool isValid3;
    bool isValid4;
    ...
}
```

assume there are more than 100 fields there, so I need to write some code to set it all to true except isValid3, so I need to retype

```
myStruct.isValid0 = true;
myStruct.isValid1 = true;
myStruct.isValid2 = true;
...
```

Is there a way to avoid this duplicate work in VSCODE or in vim?

Comment: in VSC use **Multi Cursors**, copy the lines in the struct definition and place multi cursors with `Shift+Alt+Click` and edit all lines (max 10000 in one go) at once, if you also need to generate the struct content you can use [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen) to generate text with increasing numbers

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do it in Vim, the ideal one being essentially the most intuitive one. The one you immediately think of.

One way would be to use `:help v_g_CTRL-A`:

```
i                            " enter insert mode
myStruct.isValid0 = true;    " insert the first line
<Esc>                        " leave insert mode
yy                           " yank the current line
119p                         " put it 119 times below the current line
V']                          " visually select the lines you just added
g<C-a>                       " increment the first number of each selected line
```

Here, you create all the needed lines before going on with the incrementation business. But there is another approach: doing each line creation and incrementation sequentially.

Here is how you would do it *with a recording*:

```
i                            " enter insert mode
myStruct.isValid0 = true;    " insert the first line
<Esc>                        " leave insert mode
qq                           " start recording in register q
yy                           " yank the current line
p                            " put it below the current line
<C-a>                        " increment the first number on the line
q                            " stop recording
118@q                        " replay recording 118 times
```

and this is how you would do it *manually*, with `:help :normal` and `:help ctrl-a`:

```
i                            " enter insert mode
myStruct.isValid0 = true;    " insert the first line
<Esc>                        " leave insert mode
:norm yyp^A                  " define and execute the macro on the command-line once
                             " (^A is obtained with <C-v><C-a>)
118@:                        " repeat it 118 times
```

The first method is more visual and feels more like text editing so it would probably be the most recommended today.

Years ago, the second method would have been the most recommended because macros are a very powerful tool and the ability to record them and play them back honestly feels like a super power.

As for me, I learned to value the expressivity of the command-line so I would immediately go with the third method.

--- EDIT, as requested in the comments ---

Vim is not exactly the result of someone standing at a whiteboard with a marker to design the perfect text editor. Its history is fragmented and messy and one doesn't need to squint too hard to find many cracks. Key notation is certainly one of those cracks, where one-notation-can-be-used-in-one-context-and-not-in-another-or-maybe-with-some-escaping-where-is-it-explained-in-the-docs-I-don't-remember.

Anyway, the "angle bracket" notation, `<C-a>` for `Ctrl+A`, doesn't work with `:help :normal` so we must use the literal control code `^A` instead. The problem is that `^A` is consumed by Vim so one has to find a way to insert a literal control code when needed. That's what `:help c_ctrl-v` does, just like in your shell. The doc mentions another method that I find less intuitive and too verbose so… `<C-v><C-a>` it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, it's really really helpful for me. And actually, there is another case where the fields' name are totally different, is there some better way to handle that case. For example, the stuct will be : struct MyStruct{
    bool fooValid;
    bool barValid;
    bool otherValid;
    bool anotherValid;
    bool someValid;
    ...
}

Comment: In that case, I would 1. yank the whole block of fields, 2. put it where I want my initialization to be, 3. do a substitution on what I just put.

Comment: @romainl Could you please clarify in the 3rd method what exactly is going on in in terms of `^A` and what it does? Why does `<C-v><C-a>` give rise to `^A` ?

Comment: @romainl Thanks. Boy, I typed `Ctrla` in `:` mode and was I in for a surprise. It listed in alphabetical order a bunch of stuff that I had no clue about.